# Font Awesome icons are changing to older ones

Tags: php, wordpress, font-awesome

i'm developing a Wordpress Theme, and i'm showing some social icons.

While i'm in the home page icons look great and update, but once i change to another page Google+ and Instagram change to the older version.

i'm using this code generated by fontawesome cdn in the function.php

```
wp_enqueue_style ('font-awesome', 'https://use.fontawesome.com/7bd19b97c7.css', NULL,NULL);
```

and this to display the icon:

```
<a href="<?php echo esc_url($variable); ?>"<?php echo $new_tab; ?>>
    <i class="fa fa-google-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

here's the link if you want to check http://prova.enricotedoldi.it/

Any suggestion?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a plugin called ultimate member that overrides the font awesome css. It contains another fontawsome icon css inside it(probably not the latest one) .

Just use Ctrl+U to see it.

You see that `http://prova.enricotedoldi.it/wp-content/plugins/ultimate-member/assets/css/um.min.css?ver=1.3.88` which is not present on the home page, but present on other pages.

It is below your css of fontwesome. `https://use.fontawesome.com/7bd19b97c7.css`

So it overides it on other pages but not the home page because it does not contain it.